# Cancel button to cancel SpeakAsync method doesn't respond

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, speechsynthesizer

I have a cancel button to cancel speakAsync method of a speech syntehsizer. It is called over a `PromptBuilder` and the output is set to a wavefile, as

```
reader.SetOutputToWaveFile(CurAudioFile, fmt);
reader.SpeakAsync(PB);
```

And cancel it as following:

```
private buttonCancel_Click(...)
{
    if (Utility.Warn("Are you sure you want to cancel reading the document aloud?") == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
    {
         reader.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that, when I click on the cancel button, the code is never executed! actually it become unresponsive to the button click and it is not executed!

I tried to use `Application.DoEvents()` in speak_progress but it also doesn't help!

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Are you sure that you are using `SpeakAsync` and not `Speak`?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal,Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @YacoubMassad yes, speack asynch, do you set output to a wave file?

Comment: Could you please show more of your code? Where and how do you store the reader?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I found the problem, in the speak_progress I call `Focus` for a control and it make the focus away from the button and doesn't let it be clicked!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a different thread when playing asynchronously, you are probably loosing reference to your reader object.

I suggest you to declare `reader` as a `static` property especially if you cancel it in a different event.

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem, in the speak_progress I call `Focus` for a control and it makes the focus away from the button and doesn't let it be clicked!

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the `Speak_progress` event which is called after saying each word, I call `Focus` method for a control. then it shifts focus from the cancel button frequently and the click couldn't be performed!

Hope this answer be useful for similar problems!